# Office365 Spam Report CSV missing certain events

Tags: exchange, office365

In Office365, the reporting functionality under 'Security & Compliance' allows you to create a report to show spam blocked within a custom date range. On the dashboard, the data displayed includes 'Spam Content Filtered', 'Spam IP Block', 'Spam Envelope Block' and 'Spam DBEB Filter'.

When I click on the 'Request report' button and generate a report with a custom date range, e.g. 1st December 2018 to 31st December 2018, the CSV report generated and emailed only includes 'event_type' of 'SpamContentFiltered' and ommits the other data featured when displayed on the dashboard.

How do I generate a CSV report that includes spam block of all event types and not just content filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this similar case](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/Office-365-Spam-detections-Report/td-p/131046), I’m afraid it is by default.

As others said: “most of these are blocked even before hitting the Exchange servers, so there is no information available in any report.”

Comment: I know what you mean, but that's the weird thing - The data is available as the Spam graph on the dashboard shows around 2.5k emails a day being blocked because of their source IP but that data doesn't come back in the generated CSV for that report. Thanks though, your link has helped.